# Implementing Java TCP client for C++ server

Tags: java, c++, tcp, client-server

I'm trying to implementing a TCP server-client application. Server is written in C++ and client is in Java.

1. TCP server is working with CURL and Mozilla browser but not with CHROME as well as Java client.
2. The client side script is able to hit the server but not able to retrieve the response and print from the server message.

Client.java

```
//client side 
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://192.168.1.101:12345");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

server.cpp

```
// Server side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#define PORT 12345
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 
{ 
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread; 
    struct sockaddr_in address; 
    int opt = 1; 
    int addrlen = sizeof(address); 
    char buffer[1024] = {0}; 
    char *hello = "Hello from server"; 

    // Creating socket file descriptor 
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0) 
    { 
        perror("socket failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, 
                                                &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
    { 
        perror("setsockopt"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, 
                                sizeof(address))<0) 
    { 
        perror("bind failed"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) 
    { 
        perror("listen"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, 
                    (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) 
    { 
        perror("accept"); 
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    } 
    valread = read( new_socket , buffer, 1024); 
    printf("%s\n",buffer ); 
    send(new_socket , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 ); 
    printf("Hello message sent\n"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

" Hello from server  was not displayed on console and also java giving
ERROR MESSAGE :

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1606)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045)
    at com.sri.tcptest.Client.main(Client.java:24)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.srinar.tcptest.Client.main(Client.java:34) "
```

Comment: Your Java Program is making a HTTP Request and is expecting a valid HTTP Response in return. "Hello World" is not a valid Http Response. You either have to return a valid HTTP Response on the server or look into normal TCP Connection on your Java client. Depends on what you want to implement. My guess is the raw TCP connection

Comment: Hi, i've tried with simple TCP java client, with that also i'm not able to get the data from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In server.cpp file, change:

```
char *hello = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: 17\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\nHello from server";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your server respond with invalid HTTP response.

Either make it valid, or make you client to not expect it (use plain socket instead oh HTTP client).